# Python 3 Tips to Shorten Code for Assignment and Getting Around TextIO

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I've been going through a course and trying to find ways to shorten my code. I had this assignment to open a text file, split it, then add all of the unique values to a list, then finally sort it. I passed the assignment, but I have been trying to shorten it to learn some ways to apply any shortening concepts to future codes. The main issues I keep running into is trying to make the opened file into strings to turn them into lists to append and such without read(). If I don't used read() I get back TextIO errors. I tried looking into it but what I found involved importing os and doing some other funky stuff, which seems like it would take more time.

So if anyone would mind giving me tips to more effectively code this that are beginner friendly I would be appreciative.

```
romeo = open('romeo').read()
mylist = list()
for line in romeo.split() :
    if line not in mylist:
        mylist.append(line)

mylist.sort()
print(mylist)
```

I saw that set() is pretty good for unique values, but then I don't think I can sort it. Then trying flip flop between a list and set would seem wacky. I tried those swanky one line for loop boys, but couldn't get it to work. like `for line not in mylist : mylist.append(line)` I know that's not how to do it or even close, but I don't know how to convey what I mean.

So to iterate:
1. How to get the same result without read() / getting around textIO
2. How to write this code in a more stream lined way.

I'm new to the site and coding, so hopefully I didn't trigger anyone.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Use `with open ...` so you don't leak memory. It's also shorter and more elegant. The `set` advice is much better than looping over your list again and again with `in`. You can turn it into a list and sort it after the loop: `with open("romeo") as f: print(sorted(set(f.read().split())))`

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry it took so long to reply I never got a notification. This line is just so clean and beautiful I could cry.